Opening all files from S3 folder into dataframe
I am currently opening a csv file as is:
request_csv = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='bucketname', Key='dw/file.csv')

I'd like to change this to open all files inside dw/folder (they are all CSV) into a single Dataframe. How can I approach this? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Is you question how to list all files in an s3 folder/bucket to how to append multiple files/dataframes into a single dataframe?
